# Cannot remove classList

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove a class called `active` in my code. The class `active` appears when an element is clicked with the `addEventListener` but I would like to use a function `onClick` that searches for the class `active` and removes it. Still allowing the `addEventListener` to add `active` when another element is clicked. Here is an example of what I want to achieve, in mobile I want to do the multi-level where the div stacks on-top another div and can go back to the previous div https://codyhouse.co/demo/mega-dropdown/index.html#0

```js
const dropDowns = document.querySelectorAll(".mobile-nav .dropdown");
for (var i = 0; i < dropDowns.length; i++) {
  dropDowns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.children[1].classList.add("active");
  });
}

function closeDropDown() {
  const temp = document.querySelectorAll(".mobile-nav .dropdown-content");
  temp.classList.remove("active");
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">{{ link.title }}
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
          </button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <div class="mm-row">
      <div class="mm-column">
        <div class="mm-subcategory">
          <i class="fas fa-arrow-left" onclick="closeDropDown()"></i>
          <h3>{{ link.title | link_to: link.url }}</h3>
        </div>
        {% for child_link in linklists[child_list_handle].links %} {{ child_link.title | link_to: child_link.url }} {% endfor %}
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown-feature">
        {% assign collection= collections.winter-wear %}
        <img src="{{ collection.image | img_url: '908x330' }}">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /dropdown-content -->
</div>
```

Comment: `querySelectorAll` return an array-like [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) not an `Element`. Use `querySelector` instead to get only one element, or use `forEach` and the nodelist to loop over all the elements: `temp.forEach(e => e.classList.remove("active"));`

Comment: This is not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example, he is using `this.children[1]` not `this.children[i]`, no closures here whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

The querySelectorAll function returns an array of nodes. Use the querySelector instead.

```js
function closeDropDown() {
  const temp = document.querySelector(".mobile-nav .dropdown-content");
  temp.classList.remove("active");
}
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  var element = document.querySelector("#myDIV");
  element.classList.remove("bgStyle");
}
```

```css
.bgStyle {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: coral;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the "Try it" button to remove the "mystyle" class from the DIV element:</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV" class="bgStyle">
This is a DIV element.
</div>
```

Comment: I don't get the error anymore but the code does not show any results unfortunately.

Comment: I've added a demo to ensure the code is working, if your code is not working, make sure you passed the right path to the querySelector function. Check it by Browser inspect element tab.